# How to undo the last commit

Tags: git

I forgot to add files before commit, thus I did git commit before git add.

How can I go back?

With git log I get :

```
commit 606da2c2e5fb34cf0d971dce2930c4c9d921a46f
Author: Name <email@hotmail.com>
Date:   Thu Mar 2 12:11:15 2017 +0100

    Archive detail page added
```

How can I undo this last commit?

Comment: @AvihooMamka It's duplicated. Should I accept one of the answers or should I delete the question?

Comment: If you think one of the answers here somehow gives you better solution that the answers on the origin thread, you can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer: don't do this if you pushed already and someone else may have pulled.**

If you just want to add files to that commit:

```
git add <files>
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

Otherwise you can undo and redo the commit completely, as detailed here: [How to undo last commit(s) in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-last-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 1):

You can undo last commit by:

```
 git reset --soft HEAD~
```

In case you have a typo in commit message and just want to edit the message, you can do:

```
git commit --amend
```

In case you made a commit but one of the file has an error. You can make a change and then simply update the commit.

```
git add <file_path>
git commit --amend
```

If down the history you have made a mistake with commit message, you can do:

```
git rebase-reword <commit-id>
```

**Be very careful when you are editing the history. If you have pushed this change to the origin, this can cause problems with other contributors.**